# Get peak volume of audio input on iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

On iOS 7, how do I get the current microphone input volume in a range between 0 and 1?

I've seen several approaches like [this one](https://github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer), but the results I get baffle me.

The return values of `peakPowerForChannel:` are documented to be in the range of -160 to 0 with 0 being the loudest and -160 near absolute silence.

Problem: Given a quite room and a short but loud noise, the power goes all the way up in an instant but takes very long time to drop back to quite level (way longer than the actual noise...)

What I want: Essentially I want an exact copy of the `Audio Input` patch of Quartz Composer with its `Volume Peak` output. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

To get a similar volume peak measurement, you might have to input raw audio via the iOS Audio Queue API (or the RemoteIO Audio Unit), and analyze the raw PCM waveform samples in each audio callback, looking for a magnitude maxima over your desired frame width or analysis time.